# Is there an official reason why Batman Volume 4 (New 52) omits issues 18-20?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52

While I would agree with anyone suggesting that Batman 18, 19, and 20 are simply not at the same level of greatness as the big plot arcs that surround them, I am curious about why they do not appear in a dedicated Batman volume. Is there an official (mouth of DC, Synder, Capullo, etc) statement about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A book collecting batman 0, 18-20, 28 and batman annual 2 has been announced for a march 2015 release date so they will be available as a collected edition.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too, oddly referred to as volume 6 and breaking the sequence with the doubling back.

Answer (score 5):

Batman 18 is a single story arc and 19-20 is a two story arc. They do not directly tie in to the secret city story in Batman Volume 4 so the publishers opted to leave them out. I do not believe they have been published in a collectible volume yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I did know these things (I'm current on all of the issues :-). I was just wondering if there was an official statement. There is precedent in some of the other new 52 stuff for including a small arc as part of a larger arc volume (such as the short Cheetah arc at the beginning of Justice League: Throne of Atlantis). It's not a huge deal--I own the digital versions of these "missing" issues--but I'm obsessive-compulsive and it will always slightly bother me that my hard copy Batman archive is missing some issues :-)

Comment: @BrianWarshaw This is relatively common. There are frequent one-issue side stories like that in comics that happen between story-arcs. Comic publishers often skip those issues when making collections, since those collections are meant to compile story-arcs for easy consumption. I doubt they made a specific statement in this case since it is pretty common.